# Entity Framework Code First - Tests Overlapping Each Other

Tags: testing, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

My integration tests are use a live DB that's generated using the EF initalizers. When I run the tests individually they run as expected. However when I run them all at once, I get a lot of failed tests.

I appear to have some overlapping going on. For example, I have two tests that use the same setup method. This setup method builds & populates the DB. Both tests perform the same test ACT which adds a handful of items to the DB (the same items), but what's unique is each test is looking for different calculations (instead of one big test that does a lot of things).

One way I could solve this is to do some trickery in the setup that creates a unique DB for each test that's run, that way everything stays isolated. However the EF initilization stuff isn't working when I do that because it is creating a new DB rather than dropping & replacing it iwth a new one (the latter triggers the seeding).

Ideas on how to address this? Seems like an organization of my tests... just not show how to best go about it and was looking for input. Really don't want to have to manually run each test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use test setup and tear down methods provided by your test framework and start transaction in test setup and rollback the transaction in test tear down ([example for NUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023200/entitity-framework-4-1-code-first-unit-testing-data-access-layer/7023534#7023534)). You can even put setup and tear down method to the base class for all tests and each test will after that run in its own transaction which will rollback at the end of the test and put the database to its initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Next to what Ladislav mentioned you can also use what's called a [Delta Assertion](http://xunitpatterns.com/Delta%20Assertion.html).

For example, suppose you test  adding a new `Order` to the SUT.

You could create a test that Asserts that there is exactly 1 `Order` in the database at the end of the test.

But you can also create a Delta Assertion by first checking how many Orders there are in the database at the start of the test method. Then after adding an `Order` to the SUT you test that there are `NumberOfOrdersAtStart + 1` in the database.